# How to mock `createQueryBuilder` in NestJS tests?

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have this NestJS service method which I need to test.

```ts
async getAllTests(orgId: string): Promise<Array<TestEntity>> {
  try {
    const query = this.repo.createQueryBuilder(this.tableName);
    query.where({ organization: orgId });
    const tests = await query.getMany();
    return tests;
  } catch (ex) {
    throw new InternalServerErrorException();
  }
}
```

I have this in my test file which is not really working, but I think it at least shows the direction I am trying to go.

```ts
let service: TestService;
let repo: Repository<TestEntity>;

beforeEach(async () => {
  const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [
      TestService,
      {
        provide: getRepositoryToken(TestEntity),
        useValue: {
          create: jest.fn(),
          save: jest.fn(),
          delete: jest.fn(),
          createQueryBuilder: jest.fn(() => ({
            where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
            getMany: jest.fn(),
            getOne: jest.fn(),
          })),
        },
      },
    ],
  }).compile();

  service = module.get<TestService>(TestService);
  repo = module.get<Repository<TestEntity>>(getRepositoryToken(TestEntity));
});
  
describe('getAllTests()', () => {
  it('should successfully return a list of tests', async () => {
    const qb = repo.createQueryBuilder();
    jest.spyOn(qb, 'getMany').mockResolvedValue([]);

    const result = service.getAllTests('foo');
    await expect(result).resolves.toEqual([]);
  });

  it('should throw an error when createQueryBuilder() fails', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(repo, 'createQueryBuilder').mockImplementation(() => {
      throw new Error();
    });

    const result = () => service.getAllTests('foo');
    await expect(result).rejects.toThrow(InternalServerErrorException);
  });

  it('should throw an error when createQueryBuilder().where fails', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(repo.createQueryBuilder(), 'where').mockImplementation(() => {
      throw new Error();
    });

    const result = () => service.getAllTests('foo');
    await expect(result).rejects.toThrow(InternalServerErrorException);
  });

  it('should throw an error when createQueryBuilder().getMany fails', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(repo.createQueryBuilder(), 'getMany').mockImplementation(() => {
      throw new Error();
    });

    const result = () => service.getAllTests('foo');
    await expect(result).rejects.toThrow(InternalServerErrorException);
  });
});
```

How do I mock either a return value or an error for `createQueryBuilder()` and it's methods?  Right now the first test that should actually return data actually returns `undefined`, the one that directly mocks `createQueryBuilder()` works, but the others report this:

```
Received promise resolved instead of rejected
Resolved to value: undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turns out to be that whenever `repo.createQueryBuilder()` is called it returns a new instance of that object.  Thus whenever a sub-property is spied on with Jest, when the real method is called it will return a different instance than the one that was spied upon!

Here's my solution.  I've created a standalone file `test-helpers.ts` that contains this:

```ts
export const mockRepositoryFactory = () => {
  const mockDeleteSingleton = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
  const mockExecuteSingleton = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
  const mockFromSingleton = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
  const mockGetManySingleton = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
  const mockGetOneSingleton = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
  const mockInnerJoinSingleton = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
  const mockInnerJoinAndSelectSingleton = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
  const mockOrderBySingleton = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
  const mockWhereSingleton = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();

  return {
    create: jest.fn(),
    save: jest.fn(),
    delete: jest.fn(),
    findOne: jest.fn(),
    findOneBy: jest.fn(),
    find: jest.fn(),
    createQueryBuilder: () => ({
      delete: mockDeleteSingleton,
      execute: mockExecuteSingleton,
      from: mockFromSingleton,
      getMany: mockGetManySingleton,
      getOne: mockGetOneSingleton,
      innerJoin: mockInnerJoinSingleton,
      innerJoinAndSelect: mockInnerJoinAndSelectSingleton,
      orderBy: mockOrderBySingleton,
      where: mockWhereSingleton,
    }),
  };
};
```

This will allow the exact same instance of those sub-properties to be returned when `spyOn` is called on them.

So now, within my actual `*.spec.ts` file I simply use this imported `mockRepository` as my `useFactory`, which now will be fewer lines of code as well!

```ts
import { mockRepositoryFactory} from '../testing-helpers';

beforeEach(async () => {
  const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [
      TestService,
      {
        provide: getRepositoryToken(TestEntity),
        useFactory: mockRepositoryFactory,  //<--- use it here
      },
    ],
  }).compile();
  
  service = module.get<TestService>(TestService);
  repo = module.get<Repository<TestEntity>>(getRepositoryToken(TestEntity));
});
```

Note: I originally had a static object and used `useValue`, which did work, except for the cases in which a test needed multiple repositories.  Switching to use a factory instead fixed this.

I should also note that I **highly recommend** turning on the [`resetMocks` configuration option](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#resetmocks-boolean), which I cannot believe is not turned on by default. Jest is crazy sometimes.